# Sending serialized data in Get/Post Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

Hi I have a method in my webservice as follows

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage RegenerateReport(/*string reportObject*/)
    {
       var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StringContent("Operation completed.");
        return result;
    }
```

It works fine but i actually want to be able to send a serialized JSON object to this function.

**Alternatively**, I tried using [HttpPost] tag on this function and calling from my code as follows

```
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));

        string _BaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebAPIBaseURL"];

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}{1}",
                                        _BaseUrl,
                                        "test/RegenerateReport?FileName=" + RCFileName)) as HttpWebRequest;

        // Set type to POST
        request.Method = "Post";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }


        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

         var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

It returns

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

**Update**
This error is now removed as i have added both tags [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] to my web method. Now the thing is how to pass serialized object to the web service method. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using web api or which technology?

Comment: webapi service .net 4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit some data in web service, you should always use [HttpPost].

I think your consumer is wrong and not doing a POST request. I typically use Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package and the sample code may look like this:

```
    static async Task TestApiAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:33854/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var result = await client.PostAsync("api/School", "hello", new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // if it something returns
            string resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
            Console.WriteLine(resultString);
        }
    }
```

Just substitute the parameters for your need (URL, type, body)

Answer (score 0):

As told by @MacakM, while HttpClient seems to be the ultimate solution I am sharing the exact code that worked for me.

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        var apiParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        apiParams.Add("FileName", RCFileName ?? string.Empty);
        string _BaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebAPIBaseURL"];
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_BaseUrl);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = _client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}",
                                        _BaseUrl,
                                        "test/RegenerateReport?FileName=" + RCFileName)
                                      );
        if (response.IsCompleted)
            _client.Dispose();//Dispose the client object
```

Comment: Just to add: it is really good practise to use PostAsync when you are submiting data. Also when you use Async method, you should use `await` keyword. Of course, it works like this too :)

Comment: Ok i will improve it. Thanks ! :)